# Wait for an asynchronous task in asynctask in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I have an **AsyncTask** in **Android** that runs an asynchronous task on a different thread (I don't have a hand on the Thread life but i can give a callback to the task). Is there a way to wait for the **asynchronous task** to finish to call the **postExecute** function of the **Asynctask** ?

Thanks,

Comment: Please post some code, it's not entirely clear what's the problem.

Comment: I think, we can use `Thread.sleep(time)` for this purpose.

Comment: @NigamPatro, the sleep in unpredictable for this and won't help much.

Comment: @saopayne OK, I thought like that.

Comment: I don't have any code for now, just thinking about the solution to this problem. I just know that i would have to wait for the asynchronous to complete (from a library), to use the result.

Comment: you know about onPreExecute() method of async ??

Comment: I don't think there's a way to wait as both are `asynchronous`. the former would probably finish first than the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you should do here is define a `Listener` interface, pass a reference to an object implementing that listener to your `AsyncTask`, and call this object's method from your `onPostExecute`.

```
// this is your interface
// create it in its own file or as an inner class of your task
public interface OnTaskFinishListener {
    public void onTaskFinish();
}

// add the following code to your task's class
private OnTaskFinishListener mOnTaskFinishListener;
public void setOnTaskFinishListener(OnTaskFinishListener listener) {
    mOnTaskFinishListener = listener;
}

// in your onPostExecute method call this listener like this
// this will call the implemented method on the listener that you created
if (mOnTaskFinishListener != null) {
    mOnTaskFinishListener.onTaskFinish();
}

// suppose this is where you start your task
MyBackgroundTask task = new MyBackgroundTask();

// set new listener to your task - this listener will be called
// when onPostExecutes completed -> that's what you need
task.setOnTaskFinishListener(new OnTaskFinishListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTaskFinish() {
        // implement your code here
    }
});
task.execute(); // and start the task
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather not to implement a busy-waiting strategy. Both `AsyncTask` can share a `Semaphore` that keeps one stopped while the other finishes

Init your semaphore

```
 private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);
```

Pass that object to both tasks

```
 public AsyncTask1(Semaphore semaphore){
     this.semaphore= semaphore;
 } 

 doInBackground(){
     //do something
     semaphore.acquire(); // <- Waiting till the other task finises
 }
```

And Task2

```
 public AsyncTask2(Semaphore semaphore){
     this.semaphore= semaphore;
 } 

 onPostExecute(){
   //do something
   semaphore.release();
}
```

Comment: I was searching for this for a long time, thanks a lot. But do you thing there is any side effects to using semaphores in the Android environment?

Comment: Oh, god, this answer is from a loooong time ago. With Semaphores you're using a bit of low level directives for handling concurrency. As of today, I'd recommend going for Kotlin coroutines or RxJava 2 for this task

Comment: But do you think is RxJava2 suitable for the situation here or not, I mean where we want to halt the `doInBackground()` to wait for the other AsyncTask to complete.

Comment: Totally. With RxJava you can handle several flows of data. Reading the question again I don't think I understand the question but I'd say that [`zip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) operator solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

Task1

```
   private final Callback callback;
   public AsyncTask1(Callback callback){
       this.callback = callback;
   } 
   doInBackground(){
       //do something
       while(!callback.isFinished()){
           Thread.sleep(WAIT_TIME);
       }
   }
```

Task2

```
   private final Callback callback;
   public AsyncTask2(Callback callback){
       this.callback = callback;
   } 
   onPostExecute(){
       //do something
       callback.setFinished(true);
   }

class Callback{
    private volatile boolean finished = false;
    public void setFinished(boolean finished){
        this.finished = finished;
    }
}
```